Movie with bunch of guys who has only one suit
I'm trying to find a movie which I watched like ten years ago when I was about 15. 
All I remember from it is a bunch of guys who has only one suit and they moving it from one to another. Everyone has only several minutes with the suit and they try to get into a wedding or something. 
The movie is in color and it was in English. 
I'm not sure when it released, but it looks like a new movie (not before 1999). I literally can't remember a single name of one character. 
I do remember a scene when the one with the suit got an opportunity to get into a swimming pool or Jacuzzi with one of the girls they try to tempt. 
And thanks for the answer but I don't think it's "The wonderful ice cream" - it look to old to be the one. 
Is there somebody who has a clue about what I'm taking about? 

Why were they trading the suit?  Did it give them abilities?

Its not a super power suit. It just simple suit, maybe tuxedo. It just for them look richer then they are.

It sounds a bit like The Wonderful Ice-Cream suit to me.
In East L.A., con-man Gomez convinces four strangers to pool their money to buy a luminescent vanilla ice-cream-colored suit; he intends to split for El Paso, well-dressed. The first night, each gets the suit for an hour, and each is transformed: Dominguez with his guitar and voice charms women who dance in a parade through the plaza; Martinez's shine gets his lovely neighbor's attention; street poet Villanazul captures a crowd with his political and economic vision for the east side. The suit makes Gomez a better man, so he may not bolt; but then, what do they do with the last partner, the filthy ¡Vamanos!, whose juicy-taco-eating, wine-drinking habits could ruin the suit?
